# Order Confirmation Observer Giving Internal Server Error Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, event-observer, guest-checkout

***Updated***:

I am trying to make an observer which on order confirmation, prints **This Works** in debug.log file.

When clicking on **Place Order** in checkout, the Observer gives ***500 Internal Server Error*** with this in console with this in the error log:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'My/Plugin/Observer/Dummy' not found in <b>/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php</b> on line <b>97</b>
```

Also, my checkout hangs when clicked on **Place Order**.

My **app/code/My/Plugin/Observer/Dummy.php** File:

```
<?php

namespace My\Plugin\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Dummy implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
            $quote = $event->getQuote();
        $myfile = fopen("var/log/debug.log", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, print("This Works"));
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```

My **app/code/My/Plugin/etc/events.xml** File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_commit_after">
        <observer name="my_sales_observer" instance="My/Plugin/Observer/Dummy" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Any Idea where am I doing wrong??

Comment: I assume `My/Plugin` is just a placeholder for `Infinia/SalesOrder` or that's how the files are named in your code?

Comment: Yes, its right.... its just a placeholder

Answer (score 1):

Well your observer path looks wrong to me.

Instead of

```
app/code/My/Plugin/Observer/Dummy.php
```

It should be:

```
app/code/My/Plugin/Model/Observers/Dummy.php
```

Comment: Tried that.... still gives the same error :(

Comment: I changed the namespace in php file and path in xml file to

xml instance: My/Plugin/Observer/Dummy
php namespace: My\Plugin\Observer

Is it wrong??